# Xamarin - how to reset image cache for a specific image

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

In my Xamarin app I upload a new "user profile" image on the server, then I try to update the image with the new version of the image (Noticed that the image uri is the still the same).

There is an image cache provided by Xamarin, I need to invalidate it to force the image to reload from the server. But it seems that the Image cache cannot be invalidated ! I find no solution !

I have try several solutions, but find no way ! Even when I restart the application I get the old version of the image.

I have try some stuffs like this :

(MediaImageSource as UriImageSource).CacheValidity = new TimeSpan(-1);
        FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage.InvalidateCache(MediaImageSource, FFImageLoading.Cache.CacheType.All, true);
        FFImageLoading.ImageService.Instance.InvalidateCacheAsync(FFImageLoading.Cache.CacheType.All);

But nothing work, any idea is welcome ? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do the following:

```
// this.Img is the FFImageLoading.CachedImage in my view
var source = this.Img.Source as FileImageSource;

// Reset cache using the global instance (the key is the file name, I assume it is the uri for UriImageSource)
await ImageService.Instance.InvalidateCacheEntryAsync( source.File, CacheType.All, true );

// Reassign the image source (since the binding has not changed per se, the UI may miss the change otherwise)
this.Img.Source = new FileImageSource(...);
```

This reloads the image and FFImageLoading even does a nice fade animation when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a static method in `CachedImage` that accepts any kid of `ImageSource`, so there is no need to guess the key:

```
FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage.InvalidateCache(myImageSource, CacheType.All, true);
```